# Connecting to an AWS instance on windows from CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, pem

I am trying to execute the following command on cmdline (windows) ssh -i "publicec2instance.pem" @ec2-user<>compute.amazonaws.com

but it errors out saying 
Failed to add the hosts to the list of known hosts (/home/<>/.ssh/known_hosts)

I tried to install cygwin to emulate unix cmd line to run the same command but it is not recognizing ssh itself.

Could you please point me in the right direction

Comment: Why is it downvoted ?

Comment: Normal Linux syntax for ssh is: `ssh -i keypair.pem ec2-user@DNS-NAME` -- your syntax seems somewhat backwards.

Answer (score 0):

SSH is used to connect to Amazon Linux EC2 instances.

To connect to Amazon Windows EC2 instances, use Remote Desktop (RDP).

Here is a document that will walk you this process.

[Connecting to Your Windows Instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/connecting_to_windows_instance.html)

Comment: I am connecting to Linux instance only, but from Windows.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html. Also I was able to enter the command prompt for the aws instance, but the previous line showed this warning regarding "Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts"